# Is this wifi adapter dead in the water?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kubuntu, iwlwifi

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-32-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 2 × Intel® Celeron® CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz
Memory: 3.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 500
```

Greetings I'm trying to revive an old BeeLink T4 Pro. So far so good. However the wifi does not work on any dsitro except the windows os.

Started with getting the driver info:

lspci -k

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev ff)
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

So I went on Intel's linux driver site and got the 7265 driver extracted and ran the commands.

```
    % cp iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode /lib/firmware
    % cp iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Drivers moved over successfully and rebooted.
Still not working tried quite a few things before like updating to kubuntu 23.04 and even installing lwlwifi generic, gave up and reinstalled back to 22.04.3 by doing everything above again.

Upon on closer look at everything I realize it doesn't show up properly in other locations.

rfkill list all (only blue tooth appears)

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

dmesg

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx00259cb81624: link becomes ready
pci 0000:02:00.0: not ready 1023ms after resume; giving up
pci 0000:02:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
pci 0000:02:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
```

Every time I look up the D3clod error realize it may be something with bios so I turned off Secure boot, but still nothing. It does work by plugging it into ethernet and using a wifi-usb, but I would like to try and get it working with the built in wifi adapter. Any ideas?

Comment: "wifi does not work on any dsitro except the windows os." Is this an issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows?

Comment: complete wipe and only using kubuntu now.